# Parse Facebook user get information for User class

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, authentication, parse-platform

I'm using Parse for an iOS application that requires a user log in through Facebook. Right now, when a user logs in an object is created in User, but only shows their Facebook id. How can I change this so Parse will collect the user's name, email, id, gender, etc... ? Thanks!

**Edit:**
Here's my current code in the ViewController that triggers the login.

```
let permissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]

    PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions, {
        (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if user == nil {
            NSLog("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
        } else if user.isNew {
            NSLog("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
        } else {
            NSLog("User logged in through Facebook!")
        }
    })
}
```

Since "user_profile" includes the first and last name, how do I get Parse to save this to the User class?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that to get user's basic information. In order to get more information you have to set the proper [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2).

```
[FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"!!! ERROR !!! = %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        self.email = result[@"email"];
        self.firstname = result[@"first_name"];
        self.lastname = result[@"last_name"];
        self.facebookId = result[@"id"];
        if (result[@"birtday"]) {
            self.birthday = result[@"birthday"];
        }
    }
}];
```